# How can I change the display name for each open window in TextMate?

Tags: textmate

I often have a dozen or more projects open in TextMate and am constantly switching between them.  It may seem trivial but it really interrupts my workflow when I constantly have to hunt for the project I want in the list of open application windows (where each window maps to a different project).  TextMate reports each window as `file_name -- project_name`.  These get arranged alphabetically.  This means that everytime I switch which file I am working with within a particular project, that the list of projects windows that are open gets reordered...which is why I have to hunt for the project I want every time I want to switch.  It would be a lot better if I could search a list that was alphabetically ordered by project, which would be easy if TextMate could be made to report the name of an open window in the format of `project_name -- file_name`.  Is there a way to configure TextMate to do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kwood got me started down the right path.  I really just needed the name of the setting.  I added the following two lines to my .tm_properties file:

```
windowTitleProject = '${projectDirectory:+ ${projectDirectory/^.*\///}} - '
windowTitle        = '$windowTitleProject$windowTitleSCM$TM_DISPLAYNAME'
```

This results in any files that aren't part of a project, like notes or scratch work, being prepended with a hyphen but that is fine.

The reference material that was of the most help was [section 2.2 of the TextMate manual](http://manual.textmate.org/projects#window-title).

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the title of the windows / tabs is done via the ~/.tm_properties file, see http://blog.macromates.com/2011/git-style-configuration/ as a starting point to read up on this.

In your specific case, you want to set the windowTitle variable to something like this:

```
windowTitle = "${CWD/^.*\///} – $TM_DISPLAYNAME"
```

If you are working with some kind of source code management (Git, subversion, ...), I recommend keeping the predefined $windowTitleSCM in the setting:

```
windowTitle = "${CWD/^.*\///} – $TM_DISPLAYNAME$windowTitleSCM"
```

As a side note, as it seems your main problem is to manage many open project at once: Recently there was a change how "Open Favorites" works. If you press ⌘⇧-O, all your recent projects are shown. From there, you can fuzzy search them the same way ⌘-T works.